# Docker Images disappeared after WSL2 migration

Tags: image, docker

After migrating Docker to the latest and enabling WSL2 engine, all images have disappeared when I run:

C:\docker images --all
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE

I need to recover my previous images.
Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to uncked "Use the WSL 2 based engine" then rerun my command to see that WSL 2 based engine had a different images directory.
I have exported my old images and imported them after enabling WSL2 again.[image]